# How do I compute bootstrapped cross entropy loss in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I have read some papers that use something called "Bootstrapped Cross Entropy Loss" to train their segmentation network. The idea is to focus only on the hardest k% (say 15%) of the pixels into account to improve learning performance, especially when easy pixels dominate.

Currently, I am using the standard cross entropy:

```py
loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(mask, gt)
```

How do I convert this to the bootstrapped version efficiently in PyTorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often we would also add a "warm-up" period to the loss such that the network can learn to adapt to the easy regions first and transit to the harder regions.

This implementation starts from `k=100` and continues for 20000 iterations, then linearly decay it to `k=15` for another 50000 iterations.

```py
class BootstrappedCE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, start_warm=20000, end_warm=70000, top_p=0.15):
        super().__init__()

        self.start_warm = start_warm
        self.end_warm = end_warm
        self.top_p = top_p

    def forward(self, input, target, it):
        if it < self.start_warm:
            return F.cross_entropy(input, target), 1.0

        raw_loss = F.cross_entropy(input, target, reduction='none').view(-1)
        num_pixels = raw_loss.numel()

        if it > self.end_warm:
            this_p = self.top_p
        else:
            this_p = self.top_p + (1-self.top_p)*((self.end_warm-it)/(self.end_warm-self.start_warm))
        loss, _ = torch.topk(raw_loss, int(num_pixels * this_p), sorted=False)
        return loss.mean(), this_p
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to self answer by [@hkchengrex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63735256/10886420) (for future self and API parity with PyTorch);

one could implement `functional` version first (with some additional arguments provided in [original `torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#cross-entropy)) like this (also I prefer `reduction` to be `callable` instead of predefined strings):

```
import typing

import torch


def bootstrapped_cross_entropy(
    inputs,
    targets,
    iteration,
    p: float,
    warmup: typing.Union[typing.Callable[[float, int], float], int] = -1,
    weight=None,
    ignore_index=-100,
    reduction: typing.Callable[[torch.Tensor], torch.Tensor] = torch.mean,
):
    if not 0 < p < 1:
        raise ValueError("p should be in [0, 1] range, got: {}".format(p))

    if isinstance(warmup, int):
        this_p = 1.0 if iteration < warmup else p
    elif callable(warmup):
        this_p = warmup(p, iteration)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            "warmup should be int or callable, got {}".format(type(warmup))
        )

    # Shortcut
    if this_p == 1.0:
        return torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(
            inputs, targets, weight, ignore_index=ignore_index, reduction=reduction
        )

    raw_loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(
        inputs, targets, weight=weight, ignore_index=ignore_index, reduction="none"
    ).view(-1)
    num_pixels = raw_loss.numel()

    loss, _ = torch.topk(raw_loss, int(num_pixels * this_p), sorted=False)
    return reduction(loss)
```

Also `warmup` can be specified as `callable` (taking `p` and current `iteration`) or `int` which allows for flexible or easy scheduling.

And making a class basing of `_WeightedLoss` and `iteration` incremented automatically during each call (so only `inputs` and `targets` have to be passed):

```
class BoostrappedCrossEntropy(torch.nn.modules.loss._WeightedLoss):
    def __init__(
        self,
        p: float,
        warmup: typing.Union[typing.Callable[[float, int], float], int] = -1,
        weight=None,
        ignore_index=-100,
        reduction: typing.Callable[[torch.Tensor], torch.Tensor] = torch.mean,
    ):
        self.p = p
        self.warmup = warmup
        self.ignore_index = ignore_index
        self._current_iteration = -1

        super().__init__(weight, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction=reduction)

    def forward(self, inputs, targets):
        self._current_iteration += 1
        return bootstrapped_cross_entropy(
            inputs,
            targets,
            self._current_iteration,
            self.p,
            self.warmup,
            self.weight,
            self.ignore_index,
            self.reduction,
        )
```